# Phusion Passenger + NGinx with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, nginx, rvm, passenger

indexI am trying to deploy a simple Rails 3 app on a AWS EC2 with a Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit AMI. I followed the steps in the Phusion Passenger NGinx install page. I also used RVM which was installed successfully.

My steps:

1. Install and configure RVM
2. Install Ruby 1.9.3
3. Install Rails 3.2.3
4. Install Passenger
5. Run passenger-install-nginx-module (had to use rvmsudo)
6. Created a new rails app (rails new passenger_test)
7. Added the following config section to the nginx.conf

   ```
   server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /home/ubuntu/passenger_test/public;
    passenger_enabled on
   }
   ```

I restarted nginx and the rails default public/index.html default rails page shows up but the rails.png doesn't render and "view your application's enviroment" link does not work. I have tried four different times on four fresh new server and always get the same result. Please help!

Comment: Just wanted to add that the error in the browser from the  rails.png image is the  "504 geteway timout". Tried most of the solutions mentioned for this error with no success.

Comment: Found someone who is having the same issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/385342/nginx-passenger-rails-3-2-not-responding. Will start the config of a 11.10 AMI and try to figure out what's going on with 12.04 in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Just tried Ubuntu 11.10 t1.micro and got same error. Also tried Ubuntu 11.10 on a m1.small which was somewhat successful. This time got a 404 on the rails.png which what I think is normal in the production environment. Tried changing my rack/rails environment in my nginx.conf file as described here: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app but got 500 server errors. Tried many other combination with changing the environment but still 500. Found out that if you set bot the rack_env and rails_env config option it complains about duplicate rails_env node. So went back to production and will try with a real rails app tomorrow.

p.s. The only other step I did differently on the m1.small is that I installed only rails after I ran passenger-install-nginx-module. Once NGinx and Passenger where installed and before I installed Rails I tested a simple Rack app as described here: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app and it worked!

Comment: Yup this worked but not entirely sure why. I would have to run a few more test to confirm the exact culprit. But Ubuntu 11.10 on a small instance with installing rails after passenger works!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I have the same problem: Perfect configuration in several Ubuntu virtual machines and I get the same 404 error when my Rails welcome page tries to fetch rails.png

Comment: Yes I did somewhat. For some strange reason it works fine on a small ec2 instance. Never could get it to work on a aws micro.